# How to use gmp library with R

Tags: r, biginteger, gmp

I have installed package "gmp" and in general I can use the library, e.g. call pow.bigz(), but I need to switch to the big integers and have problems:

- How to declare a big integer ("bigz"?) number?
- How to output result of gmp functions, as direct attempt results in:

```
    > cat(factorize(121), "\n")
    02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00
```

- How to access mathematical constants like e and pi?
- What would be general advices when working with gmp package, some functions making life easier?

Comment: (1) `?as.bigz`; (2) `factorize(as.bigz("121"))`; (3) what do those constants have to do with **gmp** (but try `exp(1)` and `pi` for pretty low-precision approximations); (4) that's not the type of question that SO is built to answer.

Comment: It's best to focus on one question per post since you can accept at most one answer. Plus, with questions about code, it's best to include [minimal, complete, verifiable reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5):

#Self explained examples

#eg1 big-big-numbers

```
   library(gmp)
   x <- pow.bigz(5,4^9)  #x<- 5^4^3^2
   cat("5^4^3^2, Digits: ",sizeinbase(x, b=10))
```

#eg2 big mult

```
   mul.bigz(1.2345e+276, 5.6789e+255)
```

#eg3

```
  x <- as.bigz("12345678987654321")
     factorize(x)
```